# Docker cache permuted RUN instructions

Tags: docker

If one builds an image from a Dockerfile, would permuting 2 RUN instructions:

- Create a completely new image(new hash) with the same cached layers permuted?
- No new image is created as permuting does not affect build for the same set of RUN instructions?

RUN instruction1 replaced by RUN instruction2
RUN instruction2 replaced by RUN instruction1

Answer (score 0):

If you permut the RUN instuctions a new image will be created. Here is an example:

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo abc
RUN echo cdf
```

Running `docker image build -t image1 .` And then permuting the RUN commands
and running `docker image build -t image2 .`. You will find that image1 and image2 have different ids.

Answer (score 0):

Given this minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
RUN echo text1 > file1
RUN echo text2 > file2
```

When you run:

```
docker build . -t my-image
docker inspect my-image
```

Then you get:

```
"RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:08c2295a7fa5c220b0f60c994362d290429ad92f6e0235509db91582809442f3",
            "sha256:2ce4cb064fd2dc11c0b6fe08ffed6364478f6de0a1ac115d8aa01005b4c2921a",
            "sha256:b4f880ce3a2172db2a614faf516c172d1e205bbf293daaee0174c4a5bd93d5f3"
        ]
    }
```

Now try again with permuted commands, build and inspect the image you get:

```
"RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:08c2295a7fa5c220b0f60c994362d290429ad92f6e0235509db91582809442f3",
            "sha256:812b39039b60290f4aa193d8f8bf03fbd13020dd5cfa6e6638feb68dac72cf9c",
            "sha256:451c384fb837aa70e446a36d3571123144cb497a42819b7a30348e7d49b24a0b"
        ]
    }
```

**Note:**
If your commands do not modify the file system e.g. `RUN echo text` your image would have only one layer `sha256:08c2295a7fa5c220b0f60c9943
62d290429ad92f6e0235509db91582809442f3` which represents empty FS.

**Conclusion:**
Not only a new image is created, but also new layers (i.e. the new image is not just a re-ordered list of existing layers). This is probably because the layer includes not only the contents but its parent hash as well.

See http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/ for more details.